# How to send a particular csv file as an email?

Tags: wp-mail, csv

I have created a function to run a query and create a CSV file. The CSV file will be stored in a particular folder on my server. These files are distinguished by dates.

I want to schedule an event that will run every day and send me the appropriate file with the date as an email from WordPress

```
$today_date = date('d-m-Y');
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/reports/daily-coupon-clicks/';
$filename = 'daily-coupon-clicks-'.$today_date.'.csv';
```

Couldn't figure out the set of code to do this?

Comment: Is your problem scheduling an event or calling wp_mail with an attachment?

Comment: I am not aware of how to call wp_mail with an attachment from the server

Comment: [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)'s final argument is a filename or array of filenames, which allows you to attach files from your server.